# IBM Analytics - Cognos

Tags: analytics, cognos

Certain databases require different value formats before uploading. I have values such as date, phone number, dollar amount. I've been trying to use Trim and Extract in IBM Analytics to accomplish the goal but I have not been able to succeed. For example, I want to remove () from phone number, / or - from date of birth, etc. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Phone number (561)123-4567 I want to remove (), Birthday 12/12/1971, I want to remove all slashes, Dollar amount 100,000.00 I want to remove a comma

Comment: The `TRIM` and `EXTRACT` functions in SQL are not used to upload data.  Please describe the problem better.  Also, tag the question with the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use IBM AnalyticsNow to create a report from AS/400. DOB field shows 12/12/1971 and I want to remove the slashes so that it can be accepted by another database. The same thing is with the phone number. The phone number field shows (123) 456-7890, and I want to remove the parenthesis and hyphen. Using Extract function allows me to get either Month or Day or Year only. Using Trim does not work on Date value. Using Replace as shown below does not do anything. It just returns an error Argument *N of function REPLACE not valid.

Comment: So you're using AnalyticsNow, not Cognos Analytics, you don't know what database management system you're using, and you haven't explained what you mean by upload (which appears it may be unrelated to the question).  Good luck.

Comment: I am using IBM Cognos Analytics (aka AnalyticsNow). The database where I will upload the file is unknown to me. There's an upload interface and they require slash/hyphen/parenthesis to be removed from DOB, Phone Number, SSN, etc. So, far I have used the expression Replace that works on SSN, not on Phone # and DOB. If you could help, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Searching for AnalyticsNow leads me first to a web site that is not properly secured.  Many of the search results appear to be related to FaceBook.  Plus, IBM Cognos Analytics is a BI/reporting tool.  It is not used to update data in databases.  I don't think your question relates in any way to IBM Cognos Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the extra or unwanted characters are created

If the characters are part of the data item, use the replace function on the data item

For example, replace slash with nothing:

```
replace([Item Description 1],'/','')
```

This can be nested.  For example, we want to remove the dash (-) comma (,) and exclamation point (!)

**Wow, this - is tricky!**

replace(replace(replace([Item Description 1],'-',''),'!',''),',','')

**Wow this  is tricky**

If not, check properties and adjust the data format

For example,

If the format was Currency, look for Use thousand separator.

Set that value to No

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. It returns an error "Argument *N of function REPLACE not valid".

Comment: Might be the data type.  Try to cast the column type into varchar